# Using sed in PHP to remove variable IP address

Tags: php, bash, awk, sed, grep

I've written this PHP code:

```
<?php
$IP = getHostByName(getHostName());
shell_exec('sed -e "s/$IP//g" -i /home/user/IPs.txt');
unset($IP);
?>
```

For the purpose of logging the user's IP address in variable $IP, and then removing their IP address from a list (/home/user/IPs.txt) However, browsing the script from a web browser does not work, and running it from the command line gives the output:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
```

What can I do to fix this error? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is because that the value of `$IP` is empty. You should validate `$IP` first before running the command in the shell.

Comment: you need to screen `$` sign inside your pattern with \

Answer (score 1):

The character `$` has a special meaning in `sed` which matches the end of line, to avoid the confusion, you can use **string concatenation**

```
shell_exec('sed -e "s/'.$IP.'//g" -i /home/user/IPs.txt');
```

Or if you prefer to use **curly braces** variable inside double quotes

```
shell_exec("sed -e 's/{$IP}//g' -i /home/user/IPs.txt");
```